how to send request with json/Data in Drf Spectacular
my application view is :
meta_obj = Meta.objects.filter(post = request.data.get('post_id'))

in extend_schema() how i can write request to send 'post_id' in json not form_data? my extend_schema_view is:
@extend_schema_view(
    get = extend_schema(
        description='all published post to show in Blog Page',

        parameters=[
            OpenApiRequest("post_id",OpenApiTypes.NUMBER),
            OpenApiParameter("Accept-Language", OpenApiTypes.NUMBER, OpenApiParameter.HEADER),
            ],
        responses = MetaFullSerializer
    ),
    post = extend_schema(
        description='all published post to show in Blog Page',
        parameters=[
            OpenApiParameter("Accept-Language", OpenApiTypes.NUMBER, OpenApiParameter.HEADER),
            ],
        
        responses = PostListSerializer
    )
)

with below code in extend_schema send post_id in form_data, but i want to send with JSON:
request={
    "multipart/form-data": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "post_id": {"type": "int"},},
    },
},


i used this template to send request data in a json :
request={
    "application/json": inline_serializer(
        name="InlineOneCityPatchSerializer",
        fields={
            "country_id": serializers.IntegerField(),
        },
    ),
},

